# How do I add protocol handler to firefox from extension

Tags: firefox-addon

I want to trap request for a my protocol from Firefox extension. 
For example if we type `<my-protocol name>://...` in address bar It should call a JavaScript function in an extension. I want to achieve it if possible without explicit settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- http://www.nexgenmedia.net/docs/protocol/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIProtocolHandler
- And/or google for firefox protocol handler