# Listening for a web-based protocol handler selection

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there a way that my add-on (currently SDK-based) can listen in for the choice by the user of a particular web-based protocol handler to find out its URL (but before this web-based protocol handler site is loaded)?

Comment: I don't quite get the question... Do you want to observe the user initially setting the web protocol handler, or do you want to get notified whenever the user clicks a link that has a web protocol handler attached?

Comment: I want to get notified after the user clicks a link that has a web protocol handler attached *but* only after the user chooses the specific protocol handler they will use (since Firefox keeps asking the user to pick the exact handler upon each click unless a default is chosen).

Comment: See here, it has a sdk method as well: [How do I add protocol handler to firefox from extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556144/how-do-i-add-protocol-handler-to-firefox-from-extension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap [`nsWebHandlerApp`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/uriloader/exthandler/nsWebHandlerApp.js), that is:

1. Re-register the original component under a different name.
2. Implement `nsIHandlerApp` and `nsIWebHandlerApp` yourself, passing calls back to an instance of the original component.
3. Do whatever you want in your `launchWithURI`.